# C - how to access linked list outside of the function

Tags: c, list

I have just simple question. How can I access linked list (its head), which was allocated and created in function with only int return type?

Comment: It depends. What arguments do the function take? Does the creation function emulate pass by reference? Otherwise, unless you use global variables, it's not possible.

Comment: And for future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without seeing your linked list implementation how can we possibly tell!?

Answer (score 0):

If the function already has the return type int then the created list can be passed to the caller through a parameter by reference.

For example

```
struct node
{
    // ...
};

int create( struct node **head )
{
    *head = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    // ...

    return 1;
}

//...

struct node *head = NULL;

create( &head );
```